# Why is not possible to zoom out of a storyboard in a macOS project ? (Xcode 8.2)

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I don't understand why I'm not able to zoom out of the storyboard on a macOS project. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, even the zoom options are greyed out. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like it's not supported

from [XCode 8 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html)

> Storyboard and xib files support smooth zooming across iOS, tvOS, and
>   watchOS, as well as editing at any zoom level

No mention of MacOS (this is at Xcode 8.2.1)

Comment: MacOS is completely left to rot by Apple. I can list 1000 things you can do with iOS controls that you cannot do with MacOS'. It is a shame that Apple hates MacOS.

Comment: Maybe we should go back using `nib` instead.

Comment: Two years after my initial commend and 4 years into this bug, this is already not fixed. Everybody filling this as a bug at apple, will have the report closed as duplicate. Apple does nothing. Apple hates developers so much that this is becoming ridiculous.